# User defined conversion use the casted value

Tags: c++

I have a class like this:

```
class Color{
public:
   Color() = default;
   Color(const char* hex_val): hex(hex_val) { }
private:
   std::string hex;
};
```

And I want to call it like this:

```
void my_func(Color col){ }

int main()
{
   std::string my_color = "#ffffff";
   my_func(my_color);
}
```

This gives me `no suitable conversion from string to Color.`.

My first instinct is to define a user defined conversion like this:

```
operator std::string() const { return Color(); }
```

But I can't take the casted value as an input. So I want to do something like this:

```
operator std::string(value) const { return Color(value); }
```

So it calls that constructor.

Is there a way to do this with user defined conversions or is there a different method to achieve what I'm trying to do?

Comment: Just add an appropriate constructor

Comment: `Color(const std::string& hex_val): hex(hex_val) { }`.

Comment: I do have a warning however, implicit converting constructors may seem "useful" at first but this in large projects can become a real pain (because sometimes converting constructors get chained). So I recommend to keep constructors exlicit and call them or convert methods on them explicitly when needed.

Comment: @PepijnKramer I get that, but since it's a color value, it's obvious. Seeing a string like "#FFAA11FF" one can assume it's a color.

Comment: To you maybe, but not to the compiler (or the runtime). And who knows where your strings will come from in the future. So I still recommend to not use implicit conversions, and so does "Jason Turner/C++ weekly" : [implicit conversions are evil](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=T97QJ0KBaBU)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With your class the conversion does not work, because there is no implicit conversion from `std::string` to `const char*`. And even if there were, it would not work because only 1 custom conversion step is considered. This should work

```
my_func(my_color.c_str());
```

This

```
operator std::string() const { return Color(); }
```

makes no sense. It uses a conversion from `Color` to `std::string` to implement the conversion from `Color` to `std::string`, but you want a conversion from `std::string` to `Color`. Moreover its a member function that can be called on an existing object, but then you create a new object and attempt to return that.

The conversion from `std::string` to `Color` can be achieved by providing a converting constructor (like the one you have already but with the right type):

```
Color(const std::string& hex_val): hex(hex_val) { }
```

Only if you want to be able to call  `my_func("hello");` the constructor you currently have is needed, because implicit conversions don't apply two steps of custom conversions.

Last but not least, please note that often implicit conversions are considered confusing. You can make the constructors explicit

```
explicit Color(const std::string& hex_val): hex(hex_val) { }
```

and then call them explicitly:

```
my_func(Color(my_color));
```